# Example of full-text search across multiple fields in Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j

I've seen some simple examples text searching `STARTS WITH` `name` such as:

- http://www.jexp.de/blog/html/full-text-and-spatial-search-in-neo4j-3.html
- https://blog.knoldus.com/2016/12/11/neo4j-with-scala-neo4j-vs-elasticsearch/

But I'm looking for something more along the lines of full-text search across multiple fields: `title`, `content`:

- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-full-text-search-in-postgresql-on-ubuntu-16-04

Can I see an example of how this should be done with Neo4j?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this using the [APOC Neo4j procedure library](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures). Let's say you have node labels `Book` and `Author` and you want to make a full text query across `:Book(title)`, `:Book(content)`, and `:Author(name)` and `:Author(address)`. First, use `apoc.index.addAllNodes` to create an index called `bookIndex` and specify the labels and properties to include in the index:

```
CALL apoc.index.addAllNodes('bookIndex',{
  Book: ["title","content"],
  Author:  ["name","address"]
})
```

Then, to search the index:

```
CALL apoc.index.search('bookIndex', 'River Runs Through It')
```

You can use this with more complex graph queries as well:

```
CALL apoc.index.search('bookIndex, 'River Runs Through It')
YIELD node AS book
MATCH (book)-[:IN_GENRE]->(g:Genre)
RETURN g
```

[Lucene query syntax](https://www.lucenetutorial.com/lucene-query-syntax.html) is used so you can do fuzzy search, required components of the string, etc: `'Norman Maclean~'` or `'Norman~ +Maclean'`

See the [APOC docs](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/index32.html#_text_and_lookup_indexes) for more info.